# Unable to resolve clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a basic virtual file system implemented in C++ using this repository https://github.com/dipkakwani/Virtual-file-system

But when I run main.cpp I get following errors :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "filesys::list_files()", referenced from:
      _main in main-2b20bb.o
  "filesys::create_file(char*, char*)", referenced from:
      _main in main-2b20bb.o
  "filesys::delete_file(char*)", referenced from:
      _main in main-2b20bb.o
  "filesys::search_file(char*)", referenced from:
      _main in main-2b20bb.o
  "filesys::search_keyword(char*, char*)", referenced from:
      _main in main-2b20bb.o
  "filesys::show_file_content(char*)", referenced from:
      _main in main-2b20bb.o
  "filesys::filesys(char*)", referenced from:
      _main in main-2b20bb.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any suggestions why ?

I read the another answers but I want to run this same code without any editing so any ways to get through in mac os ?

It's for my project so can't do much changes to the code that's why I am asking new question and is different from others already had answered as it has to modify the code.

> It will be good if you download the repo and run on your system

Comment: Compile `filesys.cpp` before `main.cpp`

Comment: getting same error @SombreroChicken can you run that code from github repo and see to it ?